# getHibernateTemplate save entity with default values

Tags: hibernate

several columns of my entity has default values, now i need to do the insert job.
I know i can implement the doInHibernate method and createSqlQuery (e.g. "insert into test (test_column) values(DEFAULT)") to finish it.
But is there any way to use getHibernateTemplate().save() to do it?I really don't want to set the columns to be the default values one by one.

Comment: Default values will be handled by database. Just specify default value for your column at database level and database will handle it. No need to rely on hibernate for this

Comment: @DattatreyaKugve if the column is set NOT-NULL then the data cannot insert because of NULL values while set NULL  then the column turns to be null

Comment: See my answer below for your NOT NULL requirement

Answer (score 0):

If column is set to NOT NULL and column has default value specified at database level then INSERT query generated by hibernate must not include the column so that database will adds a default value for it. You can ask hibernate to not to include a perticular column while doing INSERT using `insertable=false` in your `@Column` annotation like below.

```
 @Column(name = "test_column", insertable=false)
 private int test_column
```

A limitation with this approach is Hibernate  will always ignore "test_column" while doing insert no matter it contains value or not. Hope that is fine for you

Comment: whether i can insert values when I want while if i didn't specify the values then insert default values?

Comment: can u have a look at my answer to see if it is feasible?